# How to prevent docker exposing itself with iptables and openvpn

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn, iptables

The goal is to:

1. allow VPN clients to access the internet
2. have access to the docker subnet (e.g. 178.18.0.0/24)
3. **prevent docker from auto-exposing itself by modifying iptables**
4. manually allow docker ports to be exposed to the internet

I have solved 1 with the example config from [here](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn1xHOWTO), 2 by pushing the subnet in the `server.conf`

**Question:** How do I prevent docker from exposing ports automatically bypassing INPUT DROP iptable chains, without dropping internet connection on eth0 and tun0?

**Attempts:**

- I have tried the documented docker way: https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/ but **as soon as I apply it, it drops all internet connection for my vpn clients** - they can access the subnet of docker just fine, but can't access the internet. If I reverse DROP to ACCEPT, it's the other way around: internet works, docker subnet does not and is exposed.
- I have also tried to add `iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT` as described here: https://riptutorial.com/docker/topic/9201/iptables-with-docker - that did not change anything sadly

---

My docker related iptables entries currently look like this:

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i eth0 ! -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j DROP
```

My network looks like that:

```
eth0 - publicly facing
tun0 - vpn on 10.0.0.0/24
docker - 172.18.0.0/24
```

The entire config as of now:

```
#!/bin/bash

# A Sample OpenVPN-aware firewall.

# eth0 is connected to the internet.
# eth1 is connected to a private subnet.

# Change this subnet to correspond to your private
# ethernet subnet.  Home will use 10.0.1.0/24 and
# Office will use 10.0.0.0/24.
PRIVATE=10.0.0.0/24

# Loopback address
LOOP=127.0.0.1

# Delete old iptables rules
# and temporarily block all traffic.
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -F

# Set default policies
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

# Prevent external packets from using loopback addr
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s $LOOP -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -s $LOOP -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -d $LOOP -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -d $LOOP -j DROP

# Anything coming from the Internet should have a real Internet address
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -s 172.16.0.0/12 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -s 10.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 172.16.0.0/12 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 10.0.0.0/8 -j DROP

# Block outgoing NetBios (if you have windows machines running
# on the private subnet).  This will not affect any NetBios
# traffic that flows over the VPN tunnel, but it will stop
# local windows machines from broadcasting themselves to
# the internet.
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --sport 137:139 -o eth0 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp --sport 137:139 -o eth0 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 137:139 -o eth0 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 137:139 -o eth0 -j DROP

# Check source address validity on packets going out to internet
iptables -A FORWARD -s ! $PRIVATE -i eth1 -j DROP

# Allow local loopback
iptables -A INPUT -s $LOOP -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -d $LOOP -j ACCEPT

# Allow incoming pings (can be disabled)
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT

# Allow services such as www and ssh (can be disabled)
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport http -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT

# Allow incoming OpenVPN packets
# Duplicate the line below for each
# OpenVPN tunnel, changing --dport n
# to match the OpenVPN UDP port.
#
# In OpenVPN, the port number is
# controlled by the --port n option.
# If you put this option in the config
# file, you can remove the leading '--'
#
# If you taking the stateful firewall
# approach (see the OpenVPN HOWTO),
# then comment out the line below.

iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT

# Allow packets from TUN/TAP devices.
# When OpenVPN is run in a secure mode,
# it will authenticate packets prior
# to their arriving on a tun or tap
# interface.  Therefore, it is not
# necessary to add any filters here,
# unless you want to restrict the
# type of packets which can flow over
# the tunnel.

iptables -A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i tap+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tap+ -j ACCEPT

# Allow packets from private subnets
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT

# Keep state of connections from local machine and private subnets
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state NEW -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Docker allow only VPN by default
    iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
    iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i eth0 ! -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j DROP

# Masquerade local subnet
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s $PRIVATE -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do your current rules actually look like and your network setup?

Comment: @Seth just edited the docker related iptables rules in, otherwise it is exactly the example firewall rules from the openvpn docs linked

Comment: @Seth edited the full config in now too, instead of only linking to it

Comment: Your configuration mentions eth1, tun+, tap+. While your initial statement is that you do have eth0, tun0 and docker. Your docker is contradictory to your VPN configuration as you actively disable 10.0.0.0/24 traffic before and now you want to add an exception. This should be blocked by your previous configuration.

Comment: @Seth I assumed tun+/tap+ was a catch all in iptables, since so many iptables docs cover the same, without ever mentioning it having to be specifically e.g. tun0, so it'd also catch tun1 if I'll add it

Comment: though I am confused about the rest of your message, in the docs it says to include the subnet that should be allowed to access docker, so by "default" I indeed would want only 10.0.0.0/24 to access it and then later allow specific ports.

Comment: what you said about eth1 does make me wonder now though, they included it just to include another eth to be accessible, but does the stuff in `# Masquerade local subnet` allow eth0 to be accessible or is that exactly the issue I am facing?

Comment: `iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 10.0.0.0/8 -j DROP` is part of your "VPN" rules. Which does drop the 10 network already. Albeit in a different chain. Your docker rules are trying to add an exception to that in a different chain. You might want to sketch your network layout. Right now you have at least 3 different zones. I'm not sure about the `+` notation. Could be that it's a catch all but it's still different from what you said you had in your environment (tap as well as tun though it's related).

Comment: @Seth oh I missed that entirely, since the comment above was implying it was only for invalid packages of sorts. I've removed that and it was close to working as intended, but whenever I bring up docker containers, it cuts the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to instead put docker properly behind ufw, a great write up was posted to stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58098930/11821602 which originated from: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/4737#issuecomment-419705925

> Append the following at the end of /etc/ufw/after.rules (replace eth0
>   with your external facing interface):
>
> ```
> # Put Docker behind UFW
> *filter
> :DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
> :ufw-user-input - [0:0]
>
> -A DOCKER-USER -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
> -A DOCKER-USER -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
> -A DOCKER-USER -i eth0 -j ufw-user-input
> -A DOCKER-USER -i eth0 -j DROP
> COMMIT
> ```
>
> And undo any and all of:
>
> - Remove "iptables": "false" from /etc/docker/daemon.json
> - Revert to DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="DROP" in /etc/default/ufw
> - Remove any docker related changes to /etc/ufw/before.rules
>
> Be sure to test that everything comes up fine after a reboot.